# conver long long number to a char array in c

Tags: c, type-conversion

I have two long long numbers a and b with 8-byte each. I also have a 16-byte array arr. I want to fit the first 8-byte of the array with a, and the last 8-byte of the array with b.

I'd like to do something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    long long a = 123456;
    long long b = 654321;
    unsigned char arr[16];

    memcpy(arr, a, 8);
    memcpy(arr + 8, b, 8);

    return 0;
}
```

The compiler tells me that

> incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'long long'
>         to parameter of type 'const void *' [-Wint-conversion]

My question is how to convert the long long to bytes that can fit into my array?

Comment: The reason why memcpy doesn't work is `memcpy(arr, a ...` instead of `memcpy(arr, &a ...` No idea why people wrote all these complex answers, use memcpy, it's just a simple typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use:

```
void convertToCharArray(unsigned char *arr, long long a)
{
    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
    {
        arr[i] = (unsigned char)((((unsigned long long) a) >> (56 - (8*i))) & 0xFFu);
    }
}

int main()
{
    long long a = 123456;
    long long b = 654321;
    unsigned char arr[16];

    convertToCharArray(&arr[0], a);
    convertToCharArray(&arr[8], b);

    printf("a   => %llx\n", a);
    printf("b   => %llx\n", b);

    printf("arr =>");
    for(i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
    {
        printf("%x", arr[i]);
    }
}
```

results:

> a   => 1e240
>     b   => 9fbf1
>     arr => 000001e240000009fbf1

example [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b0a6b6bc544a7b9f)

`convertToCharArray` extract each byte of `a` and put it in different cell of array. Most significant byte is in index 0. It's same thing as this:

```
// Save MSB in 0
arr[0] = (unsigned char)((((unsigned long long) a) >> 56) & 0xFFu);
// Save second MSB in 1
arr[1] = (unsigned char)((((unsigned long long) a) >> 48) & 0xFFu);
...
// Save seventh MSB in 6
arr[6] = (unsigned char)((((unsigned long long) a) >> 8) & 0xFFu);
// Save LSB in 7
arr[7] = (unsigned char)(((unsigned long long) a) & 0xFFu);
```

operator `>>` is the "bitwise right shift" operator: it operates a shift of `n` bits on the left operand (where`n` is the right operand). So `a >> 8` shifts a to the right from 8 bits => it put second byte on place of first byte. After that, I use operator `&` which is the "bitwise and" operator to realize a mask to activate only wanted byte.

**Don't use `memcpy` to do that** (problem of portability and security)

---

And just to answer your question, `memcpy` expects to have pointer for 2 first arguments, so you have to pass `&a` and `&b`. `&` retrieves address of variable.

Comment: This works perfectly for me. BTW, could you briefly explain what you did in your convert function? It's kind of magic to me:)

Comment: That's sufficient. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You may want to consider passing the `sizeof` and using `CHAR_BIT` instead of hardcoding values. Passing exact length values may also help as well. e.g. `(unsigned char *arr, uint64_t v, size_t sz)`. You can then rewrite your mapping to bytes, iterating `0` to `sz` as `arr[i] = (unsigned char)((((uint64_t)v) >> (CHAR_BIT * (sz - 1 - i))) & 0xff);` to handle any length value. (on systems that support 64 bit values) `CHAR_BIT` is found in `limits.h`

Answer (score 0):

```
typeof union{
 long long value;
 char array[16]
}union128;

int main(){
 union128 a; a.value = 123456;
 union128 b; b.value = 654321;

 for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++){
  printf("%2X",a.array[i]);
 }
 printf("\n");

 for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++){
  printf("%2X",b.array[i]);
 }
 printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple mistake in your code: you pass the value of `a` and `b` instead of their address and you did not include `<string.h>`.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    long long a = 123456;
    long long b = 654321;
    unsigned char arr[16];

    if (sizeof(a) != 8) {
        printf("unsupported architecture\n");
        return 1;
    }

    memcpy(arr, &a, 8);
    memcpy(arr + 8, &b, 8);

    printf("stored %lld and %lld:", a, b);
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        printf(" %02X", arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
stored 123456 and 654321: 40 E2 01 00 00 00 00 00 F1 FB 09 00 00 00 00 00
```

Note that the output is implementation dependent: in the above run, byte have 8 bits and `long long` values have 64 bits stored in little endian order (with the least significant byte first).